# Proving $z^{-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(k x)e^{-z x}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(k x)}{k}e^{-z x}dx$

Tags: integration

I'm looking for a real analytic proof for the below identity

$$z^{-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(k x)e^{-z x}dx = \dfrac{1}{z^2 + k^2} =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(k x)}{k}e^{-z x}dx$$

I am working on this problem for a long time and found a very naive approach. I was wondering if there's a nice way to prove the required without using complex analysis and residue theorem. I highly appreciate your time and efforts. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate by answwering? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$$\int e^{ax}\sin(bx)dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}[a\sin(bx)-b\cos(bx)]$$
$$\int e^{ax}\cos(bx)dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}[a\cos(bx)+b\sin(bx)]$$

Using these,

$$\begin{align}z^{-1}\int_0^\infty e^{-zx}\cos(kx)dx &= \frac{z^{-1}}{z^2+k^2}\bigg[e^{-zx}(-z\cos(kx)+k\sin(kx))\bigg]_{x=0}^{\infty} \\&=\frac{z^{-1}}{z^2+k^2}(0-1(-z)) =\frac{1}{z^2+k^2}\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}\frac1k\int_0^\infty e^{-zx}\sin(kx)dx &= \frac{1/k}{z^2+k^2}\bigg[e^{-zx}(-z\sin(kx)-k\cos(kx))\bigg]_{x=0}^{\infty} \\&=\frac{1/k}{z^2+k^2}(0-1(-k)) =\frac{1}{z^2+k^2}\end{align}$$

Comment: Is the limit 0 to infinity in first 2 integrals?

Comment: The first two formulas are general, you can use them for any limits, I've used them from 0 to $\infty$ as per our need

Comment: gotcha, Thanks man!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$C =\frac1z \int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(k x)e^{-z x}dx, \>\>\>\>\>
S = \frac1k\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin(k x)}e^{-z x}dx
$$

Then

$$ kz C-kz S  = \int_{0}^{\infty}[{k \cos(k x)}- z \sin (kx)]e^{-z x}dx
={\sin(k x)}e^{-z x}\bigg|_{0}^{\infty}=0
$$

$$ z^2 C+k^2 S  = \int_{0}^{\infty}[z\cos (kx) +{k \sin(k x)}]e^{-z x}dx
=-{\cos(k x)}e^{-z x}\bigg|_{0}^{\infty}=1
$$

which yield

$$C=S = \dfrac{1}{z^2 + k^2}$$